# Why this Git pull from C# code doesn't work

Tags: c#, git

I have to pull updates from C# code but it doesn't pull the updates. I tried the command line and it worked fine.

```
    string gitCmd = "/C cd 'C:\\Users\\jean.wang\\source\\repos\\UpdateScriptRename\\vcs\\trunk' && git pull";
        Process.Start("CMD.exe", gitCmd);
```

Comment: I think cmd doesn't accept `''` as enquoting characters.

Comment: Additionally to what @BladeMight said, you don't need to use cmd.exe. Just execute git.exe directly (and don't forget to set the current working directory of the git.exe process you want to start to the trunk directory...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your string has `''` in cd, but cmd doesn't accept the `''` as enquoting character, change them to `""`, like so:

```
"/C cd \"C:\\Users\\jean.wang\\source\\repos\\UpdateScriptRename\\vcs\\trunk\" && git pull";
```

or you can even just set working directory before Process.Start:

```
string dir = "C:\\Users\\jean.wang\\source\\repos\\UpdateScriptRename\\vcs\\trun";
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(){FileName = "git.exe", Arguments = "pull", WorkingDirectory = dir});
```

Comment: You can also use `@` to remove the need for the `\\` escape sequence.